# Accessing form's elements in controller without submit

Tags: cakephp

Is there any way I can access the form elements in view like textbox or selectbox(combobox) from controller without submitting form in view?

Comment: For what purpose? There might be other options depending on what you need to do.

Comment: i got one textbox one checkbox and one combobox in view file and somehow i want to access value of this three elements from my controller. without $_GET

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. The only way data gets to the server is if its submitted, be it via normal means or ajax, post or get.

I think you are looking for a way to submit the form without reloading the page, which would be ajax. You can use something like jQuery that has a nice framework to do this easily. you can use the .post()/.get() and .serialize() methods

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/